# Java springboot application I have to create in which I have to send requests to multiple endpoint with their schedule time at once

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-services, httprequest

**Explanation - I have IP address/port and thier time frequency saved in DB.**

I have to create service or job that will run on scheduled time. It will read endpoints from db and send request to each endpoint at same time.

Example data:

```
10.20.30.111/8890 and time frequency 5 min
10.30.40.112/6764 and time frequency 2 min
```

Means that i have to create service that will send request to `10.20.30.111/8890` every 5 min and `10.30.40.112/6764` to every 2 min.

How can I create that Service that will run based on different time frequency and send request to multiple endpoints at same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject a [TaskScheduler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/TaskScheduler.html) into a configuration class of your application. Assuming that all schedule-related records of (endpoint, frequency) are already (or can be) read from the database, you can translate each of these records to a calls to `TaskScheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate` (converting the frequency to interval of type `Duration`).

For example, a skeleton would be:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class Question72238004Config
{
    // represents the database repository for tasks FooTask
    @Autowired 
    FooTaskRepository fooTaskRepository;
    
    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
        final ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        // configure task scheduler ...
        scheduler.setPoolSize(2);
        return scheduler;
    }
    
    @PostConstruct
    void setup()
    {
        final TaskScheduler scheduler = this.taskScheduler();
        // Read records of (endpoint,freq) from fooTaskRepository
        for (FooTaskEntity t: fooTaskRepository.findAll()) {
            // extract endpoint from t, build a Runnable from it
            Runnable r = ... ;
            // extract frequency and transform to Duration
            Duration d = Duration.ofMinutes(...);
            // Schedule
            scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(r, d);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks !!! What if new endpoints and frequency added later. I think that will not work becoz code you have added is in @postconstruct will excute when we start the application and all runable will be created on start. So later added endpoints will not be processed. Please correct me if missed something or if  i am wrong

Comment: @user3114629, if new endpoints are added, then you have 2 options: (a) restart the application (if updates happen rarely), or (b) have another `@Scheduled` method that recognizes additions and adds new schedules only for them. Removal is somewhat more complicated since you have to also cancel existing schedules